# Do I need to use any js file to use $q in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

please suggest any solution.....

Comment: send your complete file

Answer (score 0):

When the screen is going white indicates that you have some errors.

You have to add `$q` as a dependency in your file whether it may be a `Controller, Factory or a Service`.

**`Add '$q' via dependeny Injection.`**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', function($q,$scope) {
function task1() 
    {
        var d = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function () 
        {
           d.resolve();
         }, 1000);
         return d.promise;

    } 
})

angular.module('myApp').service('myService', function($q,$scope) {

// Add $q as Dependency.    
}
```

Comment: already added in controller and also added angular.js and angular.min.js

Answer (score 0):

We do not need to use anything than $q injection.
$timeout already returns a promise that does just that, allowing us to write this:

```
return $timeout(function() {}, 1000)
```